# Haskell list comprehension (print sqrt for element of list)

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

I have GHCi, version 7.8.3. I would like calculate the sum of the sqrt items, which are divisible by 10.

If I write `` [ x | x <- [10..100], x `mod` 10 == 0] `` or `sum [sqrt x | x <- [10..100]]` is correct.

But if I write `` sum [ sqrt x | x <- [10..100], x `mod` 10 == 0] `` when an error is displayed:

```
'<interactive>:39:1:
    No instance for (Show t0) arising from a use of ‘print’
    The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Show Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance Show Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance (Integral a, Show a) => Show (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      ...plus 23 others
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it'
```

**How to change the command , the program that was correct ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that when you use `mod`, the type of the numbers must be `Integral a => a`, and when you use `sqrt` the type of the numbers must be `Floating a => a`.  There are no types that GHC knows of that fit both of these constraints, although because you're executing it in GHCi the error message for whatever reason is mostly useless.  The error message is like that because GHCi uses `print`, which calls `show`, and for some reason that's the first constraint that gets checked.  Since there are no types with the constraints `Show`, `Integral`, and `Floating`, it doesn't type check.

Your other two examples typecheck because they only use one of `mod` or `sqrt`.  You can get the combination of the two to work using `fromIntegral` before applying `sqrt`:

```
sum [sqrt $ fromIntegral x | x <- [10..100], x `mod` 10 == 0]
```

Comment: Makes me wonder whether there are any types with plausible instances for both `Integral` as well as `Float`. I noticed something like `f x = sqrt (mod x 10)` happily typechecks defining a function of type `f :: (Floating a, Integral a) => a -> a` -- but I don't know any type `a` which would fit the bill. :-}